# Insufficient Privileges For Admin User

Tags: administration

I am Admin user .Accounts have two types of records Business Account and Person Account.

using Overage High Volume Customer Portal User license,have a two types of profile for Business Account is B2B Profile , Person Account is B2C Profile.

1. In User Detail page clicking Contact(Lookup field,B2B Profile ) its viewing Contact Detail page.
2. In User Detail page clicking Contact(lookup field,B2C Profile )its showing

> **Insufficient Privileges
>   You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.**

How to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same problem as discussed in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/give-high-volume-customer-portal-user-access-to-their-own-contact-records) thread. If you have already migrated to Customer Communities, this issue is already fixed by Salesforce so you should not get the above error. If not, you have a couple of options

A) Create a wrapper class of the fields you need, query the contact by id, and let the customer edit. Then take the wrapper and write back to the contact (certified to be working by the submitter for original thread)

B) Get a different license type like Service Cloud portal, Customer Community for read access to contact and Partner Community for full CRUD on Contacts (in addition to the full sharing model).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav kheterpal. i think Issues was Person Account record type. created some  person account records.  when  viewing person contact detail page it showing above error