# The contact of the portal user couldn't be viewed from the user record details

Tags: administration, security, sharing, permissions, profile

I'm trying to view contact of the portal user from the user object in sandbox, but can't view it and I get the following error:

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

I have checked all security settings, sharing settings, permission sets, profiles, organization-wide defaults ...every thing seems to be clear. I have tried all but couldn't find a solution, it will be great if someone helps me out with this.

FYI I am using the **Overage high volume customer portal** profile.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the discussion on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/insufficient-privileges-for-admin-user/24075#24075) thread.

If you have already migrated to Customer Communities, this issue is already fixed by Salesforce so you should not get the above error. If not, you have a couple of options

A) Create a wrapper class of the fields you need, query the contact by id, and let the customer edit. Then take the wrapper and write back to the contact (certified to be working by the submitter for original thread)

B) Get a different license type like Service Cloud portal, Customer Community for read access to contact and Partner Community for full CRUD on Contacts (in addition to the full sharing model).

Comment: I have created some users with same overage high volume portal user but tht seems to working grt i can view the detail page of contact without  any administrative permissions but the newly created users are causing problems in viewing the contact detail page.

Comment: Are the new users using the same profile as your earlier users?

Comment: Yes they both using same profile

Comment: The difference is the contact in newly  created users are person accounts

Comment: I believe that explains it. You may want to check this link again that I quoted above - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/give-high-volume-customer-portal-user-access-to-their-own-contact-records

Comment: I have seen this link is there any way to solve this without using any code